# how to navigate back to splashscreen?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a test app that prints an array. what I need is, in the same place that is showing the printed array, a back button or make the available back button turn to the index.
Below is the code that prints the array when a button is pushed (second part of the code):

```
function outputArray() {
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
document.write(arr[i]);
}

<button onclick="outputArray();">Print</button>
```

Can anyone help me.

Thanks,
Gilberto

Comment: Is your button html? Your code and question are both quite unclear. You seem to need to go through some java/android basics tutorial.

Comment: Please post question in more clear form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A splash screen is an image that appears while a game or program is
>   loading. It may also be used to describe an introduction page on a
>   website. Splash screens cover the entire screen or simply a rectangle
>   near the center of the screen.

your question is nonsense ! splash screens are used to cover up loading times in smart phones.! 
if you want to go back use :

```
history.back()
```

Comment: is right you can't go back to the splash screen on Android.

Comment: I have corrected my question.

Comment: thanks you are right. I expressed myself in a wrong way. what i need was, like a navegation button to navigate from one page to another and vice versa.